# FMDatabase - Use of unresolved identifier 'FMDatabase'

Tags: sqlite, swift, fmdb

I'm rewriting an App purely in Swift. Just starting on the Database for which I use FMDB. I took some same code out of the "iOS8 App Development Essentials". When I compile the line:

```
let locationsDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
```

It gives me a Use of Unresolved Identifier "FMDatabase" error. This part of the code reads:

```
let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String
        databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("locations.db")

        if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String) {
            let locationsDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

            etc...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding :

```
var databasePath:String!
```

on the top of the `ViewController`, because the error was saying that the databasePath was not declared.

As a consequence I declared it as a variable of type `string` that can be null (!). In my case, it worked just fine.

Comment: simply because the error was saying the databasePath was not declared. As a consequence I declared it  as a variable of type string that can be null (!). In my case, it worked just fine. Now I am far from being an expert and maybe my axplainations are not comprehensive...